Animate accordion panel using tailwind classes
I want to add Tailwind classes to animate the opening and closing of the accordion in the code below. I've added all the classes, but it doesn't have any animation. How can I achieve what I want?


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Accordion Example</title>
    <script>
      function toggleAccordionContent(element) {
        const content = element.nextElementSibling;

        if (content.classList.contains('hidden')) {
          content.classList.remove('hidden');
          content.classList.remove('max-h-0', 'opacity-0');
          content.classList.add('max-h-screen', 'opacity-100');
        } else {
          content.classList.add('hidden');
          content.classList.add('max-h-0', 'opacity-0');
          content.classList.remove('max-h-screen', 'opacity-100');
        }
      }
    </script>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss@2.2.19/dist/tailwind.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="accordion" class="space-y-4">
      <!-- Accordion Item -->
      <div
        class="group accordion-item-wrapper example-class border border-gray-300 rounded-lg"
      >
        <div
          role="button"
          class="accordion-summary block w-full p-4 transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out example-summary-class bg-gray-100 hover:bg-gray-200 cursor-pointer"
          onclick="toggleAccordionContent(this)"
        >
          <!-- Chevron or other content goes here -->
          <span class="font-semibold">Accordion Title</span>
        </div>
        <div
          data-collapse="collapse-1"
          class="hidden custom-accordion-content overflow-hidden transition-all duration-700 ease-in-out max-h-0 opacity-0 example-content-class"
        >
          <div class="p-4 bg-white">
            <!-- Content goes here -->
            <p>
              This is the content inside the accordion. You can place any HTML
              content here.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Repeat above block for additional accordion items -->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>




Transitions do not play on the same frame that an element's display gets changed from/to none.
Instead, you could consider applying visibility: hidden. This still hides the element's descendents from the element tree (i.e. accessibility tree, focus order, interactivity, etc.) but allows transitions to play.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Accordion Example</title>
    <script>
      function toggleAccordionContent(element) {
        const content = element.nextElementSibling;

        if (content.classList.contains('invisible')) {
          content.classList.remove('invisible', 'max-h-0', 'opacity-0');
          content.classList.add('max-h-screen', 'opacity-100');
        } else {
          content.classList.add('invisible', 'max-h-0', 'opacity-0');
          content.classList.remove('max-h-screen', 'opacity-100');
        }
      }
    </script>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tailwindcss@2.2.19/dist/tailwind.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="accordion" class="space-y-4">
      <!-- Accordion Item -->
      <div
        class="group accordion-item-wrapper example-class border border-gray-300 rounded-lg"
      >
        <div
          role="button"
          class="accordion-summary block w-full p-4 transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out example-summary-class bg-gray-100 hover:bg-gray-200 cursor-pointer"
          onclick="toggleAccordionContent(this)"
        >
          <!-- Chevron or other content goes here -->
          <span class="font-semibold">Accordion Title</span>
        </div>
        <div
          data-collapse="collapse-1"
          class="invisible custom-accordion-content overflow-hidden transition-all duration-700 ease-in-out max-h-0 opacity-0 example-content-class"
        >
          <div class="p-4 bg-white">
            <!-- Content goes here -->
            <p>
              This is the content inside the accordion. You can place any HTML
              content here.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- Repeat above block for additional accordion items -->
    </div>
  </body>
</html>




You can create custom animations in tailwindcss inside your tailwind.config.js configuration file. To do this, follow the instructions in the documentation.
Example for a wiggle animation :
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      // your custom keyframes animations
      keyframes: {
        wiggle: {
          '0%, 100%': { transform: 'rotate(-3deg)' },
          '50%': { transform: 'rotate(3deg)' },
        }
      }
      // your custom animation property
      animation: {
        wiggle: 'wiggle 1s ease-in-out infinite',
      }
    }
  }
}

<div class="animate-wiggle">My Animated Element</div>

